# Shading subregion under Weibull curve in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, weibull

I want to do sth like in the figure with a Weibull distribution. [image]

But somehow I can't get it to work using `stat_function`. I get `argument missing` errors. Adding `args=list(..)` does not work.

```
limitRange <- function(fun, min, max) {
  function(x) {
    y <- fun(x)
    y[x < min  |  x > max] <- NA
    return(y)
  }
}      

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,3)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dweibull, 
                args = list(shape = 2, scale = 1.12), alpha = .8, size = 1.1) + # works
  stat_function(fun = limitRange(dweibull(shape = 2, scale = 1.12), 0.0297, 0.1189),
                args = list(shape = 2, scale = 1.12), #doesn't work
                geom = "area", fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The problem isn't with `stat_function` but with `limitRange`. Run `lr = limitRange(dweibull(shape = 2, scale = 1.12), 0.0297, 0.1189)` and then run `lr(-3)` --- you get the same error. (Don't have a solution yet...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the way you call `limitRange`. It's first argument needs to be a function, but you give it `dweibull(shape = 2, scale = 1.12)`, which is not a function. It is, in fact, that causing the error:

```
dweibull(shape = 2, scale = 1.12)
# Error in dweibull(shape = 2, scale = 1.12) : 
#  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Turning that into a function works:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 2)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dweibull,
                args = list(shape = 2, scale = 1.12)) +
  stat_function(
    fun = limitRange(function(z) dweibull(z, shape = 2, scale = 1.12), 0.0297, 0.1189),
    geom = "area",
    fill = "blue",
    alpha = 0.2
  )
```

An overall cleaner way would be to give `limitRange` a `...` argument for `fun`:

```
limitRange <- function(fun, ..., min, max) {
  return(function(x) {
    y <- fun(x, ...)
    y[x < min  |  x > max] <- NA
    return(y)
  })
}

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 2)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dweibull,
                args = list(shape = 2, scale = 1.12)) +
  stat_function(
    fun = limitRange(dweibull, shape = 2, scale = 1.12, min = 0.0297,  max = 0.1189)
    geom = "area",
    fill = "blue",
    alpha = 0.2
  )
```

You will need to name the `min` and `max` arguments this way (and it may cause bugs if `fun` takes `min` and `max` arguments... more  unique names might be better).